# How to enforce providing password for devise to delete account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

how can I make devise enforce getting correct password before canceling registration (deleting account)

Comment: How can the password be asked for (and verified) before allowing the user to change their old password? It's the same idea :) Numerous examples abound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. Do something along the lines of pst's answer:  have a text box for :canceled in a form that when saved, cancels the account.  Since it would be part of the user model, devise would force the password check upon the update action.
2. Do it yourself via a button that warns (similar to the delete buttons often in Rails).  The controller that receives the request would simply do something like the following (I seem to remember that Devise uses MD5, maybe it's SHA1, SHA2, unsure- see documentation; the key is to use the same type):

   if params[:password] == Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:password])
     cancel_account(…)
     …
   end

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the key here is knowing how to encrypt params[:password] to be able to compare it to the current_user.encrypted_password

Older versions of Devise use a password_salt as well. My advice to you would be to look at how devise does this on sign in, and use the same method in your destroy action, or whatever user-facing page you have for that.